# Visual Studio 22, rename automatically

Tags: visual-studio

If you want to rename variable in VS you need to press Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R. But I want it to be done automatically without pressing any shortcut. Is there any setting or maybe plugin for that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a *simpler* option than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - then simply pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> should have you sorted; alternatively, right-click and select "Rename..."

For "automatically", you'd need to be specific; are you talking naming-rules enforcement? or...? The IDE usually doesn't do things without *some* kind of reason or interaction.

Comment: I would like that when I rename a variable it changes everywhere, without pressing anything.

Comment: @VitaliDzikavitski if you mean "if I just type without telling it": no, that isn't built-in, intentionally - at least personally, about 80% of the time I'm renaming something, it is because I'm refactoring the implementation and I *don't* want it to apply everywhere - precisely because I'm changing how everything works, and I want the existing code to keep using the pre-existing API (which I'm about to reinstate). However, a single F2 press to get what you want (or two mouse clicks): seems pretty reasonable to me

Comment: @VitaliDzikavitski What if you use the wrong variable and change it to use the new one. You would definitely not want to automatically update it everywhere!

Comment: Ok then, am I able to get rid of this [popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/media/tutorial-rename.png?view=vs-2022), so when I press F2 it would be apllyed without pressing 'aplly' button